# Order by row groups with the highest value, then by the highest value per group

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have the following table:

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 1.0 |
| 2 | 0.860 |
| 7 | 0.686 |
| 5 | 0.886 |
| 7 | 1.0 |
| 7 | 0.478 |
| 2 | 1.0 |
| 5 | 0.921 |
| 2 | 1.0 |

And want to order by Key-groups with the highest values and then by the value in descending order, as:

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 1.0 |
| 2 | 1.0 |
| 2 | 0.860 |
| 5 | 1.0 |
| 5 | 0.921 |
| 5 | 0.886 |
| 7 | 1.0 |
| 7 | 0.686 |
| 7 | 0.478 |

**EDIT 1**: when there is multiple groups with the same highest value, then the second highest would determine the order of the groups.

**EDIT 2**: updated the values in order to better represent the data better.

How can I accomplish this in SQL Server?

Comment: Use a windowed `MAX` (in the `ORDER BY`).

Comment: @Larnu , I did the following,

`SELECT *
FROM Table
ORDER BY MAX(Value) OVER (PARTITION BY Key ORDER BY Value DESC)`

But it did give the desired result.

Comment: What would you do if 2 groups had the same max value? Let's say Key=3 has 0.5 value instead of 0.7, the same as Key=1. Which one should go first and why?

Comment: @AndreyBaulin

I would say the second highest value per group. But if it is complicated, the first value is more important; it wouldn't matter that much.

To give you context, such an order is meant to be used in a backoffice application to process row groups by highest value. Per row group there could be `n` number of rows.

Comment: Your comment above says n rows per group, a comment to an answer says 10 rows per group, and your question doesn't mention it at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be late to a party, and solution is probably overcomplicated, but it should be suitable for all cases.
The idea is to pivot Values for Keys in columns [1](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4d73419dce74d7c29cb0668dcdcfcfe3),[2],... from biggest to lowest, and then just order by these columns descending.
I changed data sample a bit to make a propper tests:

```
create table t (
    [key] int,
    [value] money
)

insert into t 
values 
    (5, 1), 
    (5, 0.9212), 
    (5, 0.8867), 
    (5, 0.8394), 
    (5, 0.8279), 
    (5, 0.82), 
    (5, 0.8047), 
    (5, 0.8018), 
    (5, 0.7997), 
    (5, 0.7893), 
    (2, 1), 
    (2, 1), 
    (2, 0.8595), 
    (2, 0.7872), 
    (2, 0.7479), 
    (2, 0.7455), 
    (2, 0.7276), 
    (2, 0.7202), 
    (2, 0.6944), 
    (2, 0.6925);
```

And a script:

```
declare @temp as table([key] nvarchar(64), rn int);
declare @depth as int = 99, -- how many values you would like to take into account when you sort your Keys values
        @sql as varchar(max);

with cte_ordered as 
(-- here we find which values from keys should be compared. rn=1 - for biggest values
    select  [key], [value], 
            row_number() over (partition by [key] order by [value] desc) as rn
    from t
),
cte_columns as 
(-- distinct N values to use it in select list
    select STRING_AGG('['+cast(rn as varchar(max))+']', ',') as cols
    from (  select distinct top (@depth) rn
            from cte_ordered order by rn) as qq
), 
cte_order as 
(-- distinct N values to use it in Order by
    select STRING_AGG('['+cast(rn as varchar(max))+'] desc', ',') as ord
    from (  select distinct top (@depth) rn 
            from cte_ordered order by rn) as qq
), 
cte_dynamic as 
(
    select  '
            select  [key],
                    row_number() over(order by ' + ord + ', [key])
            from (
                    select  [key], [value], rn
                    from (  select  [key], [value], 
                                    row_number() over (partition by [key] order by [value] desc) as rn
                            from t
                    ) as tt ) as ttt
            pivot (
                    sum([value])
                    for rn in (' + cols + ')) as pv' as query 
    from cte_columns
    cross join cte_order
)

select @sql = query
from cte_dynamic;

insert into @temp([key], rn)
exec(@sql);

select t.[key], t.[value]
from t
    inner join @temp as tt
        on t.[key] = tt.[key]
order by tt.rn, t.[value] DESC
;
```

[DBfiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4d73419dce74d7c29cb0668dcdcfcfe3)

Comment: thanks for this extensive answer. However, when tested on my real data, if there is multiple groups with the same highest value, it doesn't give priority to groups with second highest value. E.g. I have groups with values g1 = {1, 1, 1, 1, 0,9, ...}, g2 = {1, 1, 0.9, 0.8, 0,7, ...}. The groups are ordered as g2, g1 instead of g1, g2.

Comment: For me it works: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=35dc7c1e10e2e10130738b9418e852d2
Are you sure you don't filter out some of values before running this script? For example. making it distinct might bring the  result you are talking about

Comment: could you test with the following values: 

insert into t
values
(5, 1),
(5, 0.9212),
(5, 0.8867),
(5, 0.8394),
(5, 0.8279),
(5, 0.82),
(5, 0.8047),
(5, 0.8018),
(5, 0.7997),
(5, 0.7893),
(2, 1),
(2, 1),
(2, 0.8595),
(2, 0.7872),
(2, 0.7479),
(2, 0.7455),
(2, 0.7276),
(2, 0.7202),
(2, 0.6944),
(2, 0.6925);

Comment: You were right. There was a bug with row_number column convertion to string and then ordering it, so the 10th value appeared in the list before the 2nd. Now fixed it. Please check it again

Comment: yes that's it. :) Thanks, I'll mark your answer as solution.

Comment: btw, the `MAX(t.[value]) OVER (PARTITION BY t.[key] ORDER BY t.[value] DESC)` in the last order by is unnecessary as `tt.rn` already has the right order. If you leave that part out, it speeds the execution tremendously.

Comment: It's unnecessary only if you have sorted values inside each group as an input.  But you are right that it can be easily optimized. Just use **t.[value] DESC** instead of a window function in the last Order by

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from the comments if you have the solution you need, but the following ordering criteria should give your resired result:

```
select * 
from t
order by Max([value]) over(partition by [key]) desc, [key], [value] desc;
```

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3f7c9960d684655c287650cd63aae823)

Comment: Hi @Stu, thanks for the query and demo. However, when I apply it to my table I don't get the desired result.

My table has multiple groups with the same highest value.

Comment: @mbrb your sample data does not though? you can order additionally by both columns, check edit.

Comment: I just edited the dummy values. Your updated query seems to work for the first order :D. That's great! it would also be desirable to give the second priority to the succeeding highest values per group.

Comment: @mbrb I'm sure you can implement that, this answers the question you asked (twice) ;-)

Comment: If we make both values of key 3 = 0.9, you will see the effect of what I mean.

I'll mark your reply as answer to the question. ;)

Comment: Perhaps sum() instead of max()

Comment: Not really, my groups have 10 rows. The sum of all of them doesn't ensure the exact order, especially if the variability is much different across groups.